# Webdriver : How to switch to a specific window?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I came across many solutions for switching between windows, one of them is:

```
Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String currentWindow : allWindows){
   driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
}
```

But, I am unable to go to a particular window. Can someone tell me how to switch to 3rd window from parent window (using java client library)?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. If you want to switch to a window first store the window id's in an array and switch to some specific window. Some thing like below. Let me know if you want more help. Happy coding.

```
Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        String[] individualHandle = new String[handles.size()];
        Iterator it = handles.iterator();
        int i =0;
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            individualHandle[i] = (String) it.next();
            i++;
        }

driver.switchTo().window(individualHandle[1]);
```

Comment: If you are not sure about which handle corresponds to which window, then you enhance the above code and do a find for a particular element in the window and if it is valid then switch to that window.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void switchWindow(String text) {
    WebDriver popup = null;
    Iterator<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles()
            .iterator();
    while (windowIterator.hasNext()) {
        String windowHandle = windowIterator.next();
        popup = driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        String title = popup.getTitle();
        if (title.contains(text)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will get you any window that contains certain text, you don't have to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

The below method will navigate to a particular window

```
public static void switchToParticularWindow(WebDriver driver, int index) throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(index));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        logger.info("Switched to new tab");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

public class WindowHandles {

```
public static WebDriver driver;


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.way2automation.com/lifetime-membership-club/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-25089\"]/a/span[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ast-desktop-header\"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a[1]")).click();
    
    Set<String> window = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it =window.iterator();
            
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String childWindow = it.next();
        String windowTitle = driver.switchTo().window(childWindow).getTitle();
        
       
       
         if(windowTitle.contains("Way2Automation"))
            {
                break;
                
            }       
    }
            
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"blueBarDOMInspector\"]/div/div/div/div[1]/a")).click();
    
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to switch to a Specific window by Index.

```
// Get all window handles
        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

// Switch to the nth window (assuming n is the index of the window you want to switch to)
        int n = 1;  // Replace with the desired window index
        String[] handles = windowHandles.toArray(new String[0]);
        driver.switchTo().window(handles[n]);
```